# EntityFramework5 Code-First Migration

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, package-managers

I am running **EntityFramework5** with **Code-First** and **Enabled Migration** with *package manager console*. After enabled migration only *Configuration.cs* file was added to *Migrations* folder, not *InitialCreate.cs*.

I change my class from

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageThubmnail { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

to

```
 public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageThubmnail { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Note:

> 1.I am new in migration database.
>
> 2.Business Objects files and DbContext class are different class libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the initial migration manually by using `add-migration "initial"` in the package manager console. If it still doesn't create a migration file, then manually delete your database and the migrations folder and do `enable-migrations` followed by `add-migration "initial"` this should work.